# VSTO XML ribbon - is there a single instance of the ribbon?

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I'm trying to understand some of the behaviors I'm experiencing in my custom outlook VSTO ribbon and the main difficulties I'm facing are tied to what seems to be a single instance of the ribbon being shared among concurrently open inspector windows (my custom ribbon is displayed for ribbon type "Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Compose"). Is there indeed a single instance of the ribbon being shared among potentially multiple instances of inspect windows? If so, how do you handle concurrent different states in the different inspector windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you do is create the one custom Ribbon and from each view you handle the items in the Ribbon that you need. Here is a question that somewhat relates to your question:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/57dc20bb-9d29-4d3e-84d2-c64de0af0244/iribbonextensibilitygetcustomui?forum=vsto

In your case you want to maintain state, that is using the same paradigm. Whenever you get focus on the composing mail you make sure the state of the Ribbon matches the state of the composing mail.

By doing so the one time loading of the Ribbon XML is no longer an issue as you have all items in one Ribbon and are able to manipulate the state for each of the composed mails.

Comment: thank you for confirming that indeed a single instance of my custom ribbon get created no matter how many inspector windows concurrently display it. What is bugging me is that having a single *shared* instance of the ribbon seems to me to be causing repeated execution of logic previously already executed: when for example switching from one compose window to another ribbon state gets reset to reflect the underlying *state* for the mail. Can't this be somehow avoided?